# android:minSdkVersion="4" causing strange problems

Tags: android

I built my applications without specifying a minimum sdk in the beginning. However after I added that line to publish to market I found my applications are behaving very differently for example buttons are smaller, etc... In particular I'm having problems with an application that records sound which was working fine when no minimum sdk was specified, but crashes when I specify one. I've tried specifying the minsdk to that of my phone which is 7, but that doesn't seem to help. 
What's the default minimum sdk when none is specified? I just want my application to run like it does normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a minimum or target SDK version you get a lot of compatibility mode behavior. The device you're running on is probably a HDPI device and you were probably looking at a UI scaled for compatibility mode before you added the minSdkVersion, hence the smaller buttons - your app is now running at the device's native resolution.

Apps that target SDK 3 and below acquire several permissions by default that must be explicitly requested by apps targeting newer SDK versions. Check your exception message when your app crashes, it might be a security exception for a permission that you need to explicitly request in your manifest.

See the following link for more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I chose to go the easy route and just set the minimum to 3. Next time through I'll probably redo things, but I wanted to get it out before xmas.